# Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager' - Android

Tags: android, eclipse

How to add getSupportFragmentManager inside the Fragment?

```
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.calendar1, caldroidFragment);
    t.commit();
```

getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager is not accepted. Thank you.

Comment: In a `Fragment`, it's just `getFragmentManager()`. Unless you're dealing with child `Fragment`s, in which case you'd use `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: @MikeM. , Thanks, It's worked now!

Comment: No problem. I'll just vote this a duplicate so you can close out your question. Just select the "That solved my problem!" button. Thanks. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

your Activity must the FragmentActivty from the support library.

[FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)

[support library setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can have safety check first.

```
if (getActivity() instanceof FragmentActivity) {
    FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) getActivity();
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
}
```

We know that fragment is very dependent to Fragment activity so we can call it inside.